# Invalid get index in Godot

Tags: godot, godot4, godot3

I can't resolve a problem in my game. I copied the code from a youtube video but I can't resolve my error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqxzv.png)

I read the error message and tried to initialize the variable but nothing works.

If you can help me please.

Comment: show us your global script please. can't help without seeing all details